# How to display Text during Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I inherited by my ex collegue a Unity game. I need to display a label in my scene. The label should be contains the text "what is your level of fear?"
The user should be throught Logitech steering wheel, using the rotation button select a number from 0 to 9.

Now I m new user of unity and I want to start this task step by step. My Unity project have a Init scene that can start other scenes.
In my Init scene I create this static component (FearTest):
[image]

This component have a RedDot (a simple red dot) and textAnsia2 that contains the text that I need to display.
This is my class FreatTest:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
namespace DrivingTest
{
    public class FearTest : MonoBehaviour
    {
        //public GameObject redDot;
        public TextMeshPro textAnsia2;
        public TextMesh textAnsia3;
     
        public int shouldEvaluateTest = 0; // 0 - false, 1 - true
        public int secondsInterval;
        public int secondsToDisaply;
        public int radiusR1;
        public int radiusR2;
        public int reactionTestDuration;
        public int maxDots;
        public float dotRadius = 1;
        private float endTime;
        private float dotDisaplyAtTime;
        private List<float> dotDisplayReactTime = new List<float>();
        private int missedSignals;
        private int currentDotsCount;
        private bool isReactionAlreadyGiven;
        public bool ShouldEvaluateTest
        {
            get
            {
                return shouldEvaluateTest != 0;
            }
        }
     
        void OnEnable()
        {
            GameManager.TestSceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        }
        private void OnDisable()
        {
            GameManager.TestSceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        }
        #region Scene Loaded
        private void OnSceneLoaded(eTESTS test)
        {
            if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != test.ToString())
                return;
            Reset();
            GetApiParams();
        }
        #endregion
        private void GetApiParams()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            if (!GameManager.Instance)
            {
                Init();
                return;
            }
#endif
            Debug.Log("called rt");
            NextTestOutput nextTestOutput = GameManager.Instance.currentTest;
            if (nextTestOutput.content != null && nextTestOutput.content.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in nextTestOutput.content[0].listInputParameter)
                {
                    switch ((ePARAMETERS)item.id)
                    {
                        case ePARAMETERS.RT_ENABLE:
                            shouldEvaluateTest = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RT_DURATION:
                            reactionTestDuration = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_FREQ:
                            secondsInterval = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_MAX_COUNT:
                            maxDots = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_RADIUS_R1:
                            radiusR1 = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_RADIUS_R2:
                            radiusR2 = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_SIZE:
                            dotRadius = float.Parse(item.Value)/10f;
                            break;
                        case ePARAMETERS.RED_DOT_TIME:
                            secondsToDisaply = System.Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Debug.Log("called rt "+ shouldEvaluateTest);
                /*if (ShouldEvaluateTest)
                {
                    Init();
                }*/
                Init();//dopo bisogna sistemare il shoudl evaluatetest
            }
        }
        Coroutine displayCoroutine;
        public void Init()
        {
            endTime = Time.time + reactionTestDuration + 10;
            SetRedDotSize();
            displayCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RedDotDisplay());
        }
        private IEnumerator RedDotDisplay()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            while (true)
            {
                SetRandomDotPosition();
                RedDot(true);
                isReactionAlreadyGiven = false;
                dotDisaplyAtTime = Time.time;
                currentDotsCount++;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(secondsToDisaply);
                if(!isReactionAlreadyGiven)
                {
                    missedSignals++;
                }
                RedDot(false);
                if ((reactionTestDuration > 0 && endTime <= Time.time) || (maxDots > 0 && currentDotsCount >= maxDots))
                    break;
                float waitTime = secondsInterval - secondsToDisaply;
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            }
        }
        private void Update()
        {
            if (!ShouldEvaluateTest)
                return;
            if (!isReactionAlreadyGiven && /*redDot.activeSelf &&*/ (LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0) && LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, 23)))
            {
                isReactionAlreadyGiven = true;
                float reactionTime = Time.time - dotDisaplyAtTime;
                Debug.Log("Reaction Time RT : " + reactionTime);
                RedDot(false);
                dotDisplayReactTime.Add(reactionTime);
            }
        }
        public double GetReactionTimeAvg()
        {
            double avg = 0;
            foreach (var item in dotDisplayReactTime)
            {
                avg += item;
            }
            //avg / currentDotsCount
            return avg / (float)dotDisplayReactTime.Count;
        }
        public double GetMissedSignals()
        {
            return ((float) missedSignals / (float) currentDotsCount) * 100;
        }
        private void RedDot(bool state)
        {
            //redDot.SetActive(state);
            textAnsia2.SetText("Pippo 2");
         
        }
        private void SetRedDotSize()
        {
            //redDot.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
            textAnsia2.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
            textAnsia3.transform.localScale *= dotRadius;
        }
        private void SetRandomDotPosition()
        {
            //redDot.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = GetRandomPointBetweenTwoCircles(radiusR1, radiusR2)*scale;
            float scale = ((Screen.height*0.9f) / radiusR2) * 0.9f;
            Vector3 pos = GetRandomPointBetweenTwoCircles(radiusR1, radiusR2) * scale;
            Debug.Log("RT temp pos : " + pos);
            pos = new Vector3(500, 500, 0);
            Debug.Log("RT pos : " + pos);
          //  redDot.transform.position = pos;
            Vector3 pos2 = new Vector3(20, 20, 0);
            Debug.Log("text ansia 2 : " + pos2);
            textAnsia2.transform.position = pos2;
            textAnsia3.transform.position = pos;
        }
        #region Getting Red Dot b/w 2 cricles
        /*
         Code from : https://gist.github.com/Ashwinning/89fa09b3aa3de4fd72c946a874b77658
        */
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random point in the space between two concentric circles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="minRadius"></param>
        /// <param name="maxRadius"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Vector3 GetRandomPointBetweenTwoCircles(float minRadius, float maxRadius)
        {
            //Get a point on a unit circle (radius = 1) by normalizing a random point inside unit circle.
            Vector3 randomUnitPoint = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized;
            //Now get a random point between the corresponding points on both the circles
            return GetRandomVector3Between(randomUnitPoint * minRadius, randomUnitPoint * maxRadius);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a random vector3 between min and max. (Inclusive)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="UnityEngine.Vector3"/>.</returns>
        /// <param name="min">Minimum.</param>
        /// <param name="max">Max.</param>
        Vector3 GetRandomVector3Between(Vector3 min, Vector3 max)
        {
            return min + Random.Range(0, 1) * (max - min);
        }
        #endregion
        #region Reset
        private void Reset()
        {
            if (displayCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(displayCoroutine);
            RedDot(false);
            shouldEvaluateTest = 0;
            reactionTestDuration = 0;
            secondsInterval = 0;
            missedSignals = 0;
            maxDots = 0;
            radiusR1 = 0;
            radiusR2 = 0;
            dotRadius = 1;
            secondsToDisaply = 0;
            endTime = 0;
            dotDisaplyAtTime = 0;
            dotDisplayReactTime.Clear();
            //redDot.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            textAnsia2.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            textAnsia3.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            currentDotsCount = 0;
            isReactionAlreadyGiven = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

When "SetRandomDotPosition" method is called, in my scene I can display in a random position of the screen the RedDot (that is a simple image with a red dot), and I need to display also my text.
The red dot is displayed, but I m not able to display the text.
How can I fixed it ?